# Wrting $\operatorname{Eq}\bigl(\prod_{i\in I}X_i\rightrightarrows\prod_{j\in J}Y_j\bigr)$ as a limit of a single diagram

Tags: category-theory

Let $D\colon \mathcal{I}\longrightarrow\mathcal{C}$ be a small diagram in the category $\mathcal{C}$. It is rather well known that a limit of $D$ can be computed as the equalizer of the two maps $$\prod_{i\in\mathcal{I}}D(i)\rightrightarrows\prod_{(f\colon i\to j)\in\mathcal{I}}D(j)$$
mapping a family $\{x_i\}$ to $\{x_j\}_{f\colon i\to j}$ resp. $\{D(f)(x_i)\}_{f\colon i\to j}$.

My question is wether conversely it is possible to write the equalizer of two maps of products $\operatorname{Eq}\bigl(\prod_{i\in I}X_i\rightrightarrows\prod_{j\in J}Y_j\bigr)$ as a limit of a diagram having the objects $X_i$ and $Y_j$ as its vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not. You can find an explicit counterexample in the opposite of the category of abelian groups: see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204792/is-every-abelian-group-a-colimit-of-copies-of-z).

Every abelian group is a coequalizer of maps between two coproducts of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, but the abelian groups which can be written as a colimit of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ are called "simply presented" and many abelian groups are not.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. Actually my intention is pretty much related to your MO question. Namely I was thinking about why a finitely presented abelian group can be written as a finite colimit of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @John: it is. This reduces to showing that the coequalizer of a pair of maps between finitely presented abelian groups $A, B$ is finitely presented. Concretely this amounts to quotienting $B$ by a finite set of relations given by a finite choice of generators of $A$. There is also an abstract way to write this proof that will work in greater generality; see https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/04/25/compact-objects/ for some details.

Answer (score 1):

A more elementary example.

Take the category of vector spaces over your favourite field.

Writing $V^*$ for the dual of $V$, 
$$\text{lim}_i(V_i^*)\cong(\text{colim}_iV_i)^*,$$
so every limit $\text{lim}_iV_i$ of finite dimensional vector spaces is a dual, $(\text{colim}_iV_i^*)^*$, and so can’t have countably infinite dimension.

But a countable dimensional vector space is an equalizer of maps between products of finite dimensional vector spaces.